# Swift 5: JSON object array to swift structure

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct

i have no experience with creating apps in swift but please bear with us. I would like to get data from public API in JSON format and create struct in swift, so i've found some tutorials but i' am facing issues.

I'm pretty sure that api returns json values, i've tested it via

```
let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

and i've got correct response.

But when i try to make objects from this response

```
let stations = try JSONDecoder().decode([Station].self, from: data)
                print(stations) // returns nil
```

It prints this error:

```
//Error:  typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "gegrLat", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

All of my code with data structures:

```
import UIKit

struct Commune: Codable{
    var communeName: String
    var districtName: String
    var proviceName: String
}

struct City: Codable{
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var commune: Commune
}

struct Station: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var stationName: String
    var gegrLat: Double
    var gegrLon: Double
    var city: City
    var addressStreet: String?
}

class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController

        let jsonUrlString = "http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            //let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            //print(dataAsString) //working fine, returns string with data

            //let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject( with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
            //print(json) //also working fine, returns json

            do{
                let stations = try JSONDecoder().decode([Station].self, from: data)
                print(stations) // returns nil
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error: ", jsonErr)
                //Error:  typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "gegrLat", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

The API response is array of objects, its look like:
[response example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnxXp.png) So i want to display list of this object in my application.

I would be really gratefull for any help

Comment: The error is telling you that `gegrLat` is a `String` in the JSON, not a `Double`.

Comment: There is a very simple JSON rule: **Everything** in double quotes is string, even `"12.4"` and `"false"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your "Station" structure so gegrLon and  gegrLat are Strings:

```
struct Station: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var stationName: String
    var gegrLat: String
    var gegrLon: String
    var city: City
    var addressStreet: String?
}
```

i.e your error is saying that is `Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.`

Comment: Im so dumb, i didn't see it before. Now it works, thank you <3

Comment: Glad I could help. (If this was the right answer, you should let future users know by clicking the check mark next to it.)

Comment: It's better to instead implement `init(from decoder: Decoder)`, and use it to parse those strings into the proper datatype, like a `CLLocation` or `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. Otherwise, your inter code will be litered with repeated parsing, probably force unwraps, and it would be a mess

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I think for this example using a String makes sense.

Comment: @RickySanchez It most certainly doesn't. I can basically guarantee you that one of the next steps following parsing data like this is asking "how do I find the km distance between two pairs of strings that represent lat and long?", and if you don't have `CLLocations`, well... good luck with that

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Yes, I understand that. I'm saying specifically for this user who asked the question, they just wanted the String, and for this SPECIFIC answer it was unnecessary for me to add that. Thanks for your responses!

Comment: @RickySanchez Well OP didn't explicitly require a string. The JSON just happens to encode this data as a string (not surprising, there's no JSON GPS Coord primitive type), and storing a string is the least resistance from OP's error to the short term goal (just get it to parse, at all). That doesn't mean it's the most appropriate overall (to have a data model that works well), *which is a goal that can't be ignored*. It's not like this data will just be decoded once and then sucked in a vacuum, never to be used.